# JSHint and "Tolerate Variable Shadowing"

Tags: jshint

Does anybody know why this code does not produce errors in JSHint?

I think it should give me a variable shadowing warning but I'm not getting one.

I have "Tolerate Variable shadowing" as false am using the visual studio plugin.

```
RES.test = function () {
    var test, f;

    f = function () {
        var test;

        window.alert(test);
    };
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled onto this too. Apparently JSHint developers' definition of "shadowing" is not what you expect. For them, hiding a variable name coming from a closure is not shadowing. And yes, I find it strange too :-)

If you look at their test suite, they mean something like "redefinition", where you do

```
var a = 1;
...
var a = 2;
```

look at their test case: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/tests/stable/unit/fixtures/redef.js

Comment: Good spot, I hadn't noticed this. It's strange how jshint / lint is so picky about some pretty mundane things (eg ++) but doesn't latch on to this.